# How to get HTTP RESPONSE CODE in CXF interceptor?

Tags: java, cxf, interceptor

I have web service based on Apache CXF. I wrote interceptor for logging some specific stuff that's included http response code.

```
public class MyOutInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {

    public MyOutInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.SEND);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
        Integer responseCode = (Integer) message.get(Message.RESPONSE_CODE);
        //...
    }
}
```

BUT!!! `responseCode` is `null`. Even if I change the interceptor phase, it's always `null`.
How can I get http response code in CXF interceptor?

---

**UPD**. Application Spring/CXF configuration: https://gist.github.com/alexiuscrow/b5ceb2df7d652a77cd788454e0792211

---

**UPD**. Temporary solution

```
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
    Integer responseCode = (Integer) message.get(Message.RESPONSE_CODE);
    if (null == responseCode) {
        HttpServletResponseWrapper responseWrapper = 
           (HttpServletResponseWrapper) message.get(AbstractHTTPDestination.HTTP_RESPONSE);
        responseCode = responseWrapper.getStatus();
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: I had the similar issue and the Temporary solution worked for me. Thanks for that. However, I used the HttpServletResponse interface, as opposed to the Wrapper class.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've registered the interceptor for `outinterceptor` not for `outFaultInterceptor or FaultInterceptor` etc. Here is validated example.

```
import org.apache.cxf.annotations.Provider;
import org.apache.cxf.annotations.Provider.Type;
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault;
import org.apache.cxf.message.Message;
import org.apache.cxf.phase.AbstractPhaseInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.phase.Phase;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Provider(value=Type.OutInterceptor)
public class KpOutInterceptor2 extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {

    private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KpOutInterceptor2.class);

    public KpOutInterceptor2() {
        super(Phase.SEND);

    }   

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
        LOG.info("JAXRS response status code is {}", message.get(Message.RESPONSE_CODE));
    }

}
```

Or much better way use JAXRS 2.0 standard Filters.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Provider
public class KpOutInterceptor implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KpOutInterceptor.class);

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext reqCtx, ContainerResponseContext resCtx) throws IOException {

        LOG.info("JAXRS response status code is {}", resCtx.getStatus());

    }

}
```

Comment: I checked. It bound to `outInterceptors`.

Comment: Check the first solution, it same as what you have already implemented but I guess you had registered the interceptor to different one.

Comment: Interceptor is configured with JAX-WS. May it be the cause of a problem? Application Spring/CXF configuration: https://gist.github.com/alexiuscrow/b5ceb2df7d652a77cd788454e0792211